# Error: (vlog-13069) cad_property.sv(5): near "case": syntax error, unexpected case

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

```
property clk_req_check;
@(posedge upbm_clk) disable iff (~upbm_reset_n)

//@(posedge upbm_clk);
 case (sb_adrc)
   2'b00 : 1'b1 |-> (clk_req[0] == 1'b1) [*] (sb_adrc != 2'b00);
   2'b01 : 1'b1 |-> (clk_req[1] == 1'b1) [*] (sb_adrc != 2'b01);
   2'b10 : 1'b1 |-> (clk_req[2] == 1'b1) [*] (sb_adrc != 2'b10);
   2'b11 : 1'b1 |-> (clk_req[3] == 1'b1) [*] (sb_adrc != 2'b11);
   default : 1'b0;
  endcase
endproperty: clk_req_check
```

** Error: (vlog-13069) cad_property.sv(5): near "case": syntax error, unexpected case.

without disable_iff
** Error: (vlog-13069) cad_property.sv(3): near "case": syntax error, unexpected case, expecting disable.

Comment: Your question would be better understood if you added some context. What kind of environment is this, and how is this code being called?

Answer (score 0):

`case/endcase` within an assertion may not supported in your version of Questa.

Comment: you can just cut paste the code i shared and the error will pop up I.E vlog -sv  abc.sv

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting, I've never tried writing a case statement inside a concurrent assertion, not sure if that is allowed. Thinking about it though, you want to simultaneously be checking all 4 values of `sb_adrc` with concurrent assertions (which run constantly on every `upbm_clk`), which feels to me that you need 4 separate concurrent assertions. Each one similar to the following:

```
property clk_req_check;
  @(posedge upbm_clk) disable iff (~upbm_reset_n)
    sb_adrc == 2'b00 |-> (clk_req[0] == 1'b1) ##1 (sb_adrc != 2'b00)
endproperty
```